# Why can Apache proxypass this when nginx can't?

Tags: nginx, ssl, apache2, proxypass, websocket

I have an SSL host on my apache server with the following in the VirtualHost:

```
    <VirtualHost 217.147.92.100:443>
    ServerName server.com

    ServerAdmin email@email.com
    DocumentRoot /somepath/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/something/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/something/privkey.pem

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass "/rtapi/" "ws://localhost:38120/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/rtapi/" "ws://localhost:38120/"

    <Directory /somepath/>
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Good so far? Notice the proxypass for the /rtapi/ folder. Good ol' apache works a charm, as usual.

Now for our unhappy camper nginx from whom I ask much less:

```
server {
listen 45108 ssl;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/something/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/something/privkey.pem;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:38120;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

}

All I'm looking for from nginx is to slap on an SSL wrapper on my websocket service and proxy it along.

I get:

```
2017/08/24 19:55:01 [error] 25018#0: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 71.192.225.239, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:38120/", host: "api.speedracing.tv:45108"
```

Which seems useful. Oh! My little websocket server must not be responding... but wait a second. Surely the server must be running because it accepts the proxied requests from apache. Clearly the logical conclusion is that nginx is the connection but I'm not really seeing why or how.

Comment: You've configured Apache to have a directory of /rtapi/ but Nginx is on the root. Is that relevant?

Comment: This may be something a little too obvious: What's providing the websocket service on port 38120?  Is it also Apache?  Are you stopping Apache to test nginx?  Otherwise, do you have any relevant firewall rules?

Comment: @Tim That is intentional.

Comment: @CedricKnight The websocket service is provided by a standalone daemon. Although it's not relevant, Apache is NOT stopped, as this is a production server. The only meaningful firewall rules we have are banning several IP addresses in China.